# Java error: bad operand types for binary operator '!='

Tags: java

when I run the code below, but it doesn't work and error like this

`java:47: error: bad operand types for binary operator '!='
        if ( x != false && x != p && x != q){
               ^
  first type:  Node
  second type: boolean

```
import java.util.*;

class Tree{
static class Node {
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node parent;
    Node (int data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
Node root;
HashMap<Integer, Node> rootMap;
Tree ( int size ){
    rootMap = new HashMap<Integer, Node>();
    root = makeBST(0, size - 1, null);
}
Node makeBST(int start, int end, Node parent){
    if ( start > end) return null;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    Node node = new Node(mid);
    node.left = makeBST(start, mid -1, node);
    node.right = makeBST(mid + 1, end, node);
    node.parent = parent;
    rootMap.put(mid, node);
    return node;
}
Node getNode(int data){
    return rootMap.get(data);
}

Node commonAncestor( int d1, int d2){
    Node p = getNode(d1);
    Node q = getNode(d2);
    return commonAncestor(root, p, q);
}
Node commonAncestor(Node root, Node p, Node q){
    if ( root == null ) return null;
    if ( root == p && root == q) return root;
    Node x = commonAncestor(root.left, p, q);
    if ( x != false  &&  x != p  &&  x != q){
        return x;
    }
    Node y = commonAncestor(root.right, p, q);
    if ( y != null && y != p && y != q){
        return y;
    }
    if ( x != null && y != null){
        return root;
    }else if ( root == p || root == q){
        return root;
    } else {
        return x == null ? y : x;
    }
}
}
public class FindAncestor4{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Tree t = new Tree(10);
        Tree.Node fa = t.commonAncestor(5, 8);
        System.out.println("The first common ancestor is " + fa.data);
    }
}`
```

What should I do? I'm really like to appreciate to answer me the reason why occur this error, and how to solve it.

Comment: `x` is not boolean, so you can't compare it to `false`

Answer (score 2):

x is a Node object and it cannot be compared with false which is boolean

Answer (score 1):

Since Java is strongly typed, you need to make sure that the two variables you are comparing are actually comparable, in order to use binary operators like `+ - / * != == > < >= <=`. In your secific case, you are comparing an object of type `Node` to an object of type `boolean`. Firstly, boolean is a *primitive type*. Among other things, this means that it does not inherit `Object`, which is the root from which all non-primitive types in Java stem.

If you take an `int` to a `long`, the `int` will be implicitly converted to a `long` and then compared.

e.g.

```
int a = 9;
long b = 9;
if(a == b){
  System.out.print("same");
} else {
  System.out.print("different");
}
```

Will return "same".

If it is not possible to implicitly cast the type, then you will get the error you experienced.

You need to figure out how to get the comparison you need. For instance, if you want to see if the object is a node, check with `typeof`

Answer (score 0):

the compiler tells you everything:

`bad operand types for binary operator '!='`

`first type: Node second type: boolean`

I guess you are trying to write `x!=null`?

Comment: read the OP's question, you do not need to guess that he is comparing to null. he shows the code.